# How to put different headIndent (alignment) for every paragraph in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In my application i need to **align all the paragraph** differently.

like, first paragraph's **headIndent** is 0.0f then second's 10.0f and third's 3.0f.

i am giving all the paragraph style to **textview.attributedText**. and it took only **one style**.

Here whole text will come **dynamically by Typing**. means when User will type in text view at that time. so, there are no static string to do this.

I am placing all the characters in UITextView by this...

```
 UIFont *fontBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
 attributesHelveticaBold = @{NSFontAttributeName :fontBold};

 UIFont *fontNormal = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
 attributesNormal = @{NSFontAttributeName :fontNormal};

 if (varBold== 1) {
     [textView setTypingAttributes:attributesHelveticaBold];
 }
 else {
     [textView setTypingAttributes:attributesNormal];
 }
```

And i want to get this kind of result in text view

[image]

When i am typing the typing become slow too.

but i think i'll come over that issue but for now i stuck on this alignment problem.

how to do it when bullet point come and when different text come.

any kind of link, code, tutorial will be great help...

**---------- Edit : ----------**

Please have a look in **Evernote**'s application.
I need to do the exactly same thing in my app. for alignment of second,third,etc line when bullet come.

**-------- Edit after searching :-------**

I searched too much for this but ain't find anything by googling.
So, now i am asking if anyone now about How to give any paragraph style or any attribute style to a paragraph and just leave it as it is on text view and then perform other paragraph style on second paragraph. at this time the first paragraph will not pass throw "shouldChangeTextInRange" method.

yes, it's quite confusing whatever i am saying.

so i explaining it in general...

**if user set the text view's first paragraph's headIndent=7.0f then when user will type next paragraph and set the headIndent = 13.0f then first paragraph will stay as it is in textview and just running paragraph will come in a chapter (means in a method).**

right now i am doing these thing in **shouldChangeTextInRange** method to do style for each paragraph.

```
varStaringPointOfString = 0;
varEndingPointOfString = 0;

NSArray *sampleArrToGetattrStr = [txtViewOfNotes.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (int i=0; i<[sampleArrToGetattrStr count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strtostoreLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sampleArrToGetattrStr objectAtIndex:i]];
    varStaringPointOfString = (int)strtostoreLength.length + varEndingPointOfString;

    if ([strtostoreLength hasPrefix:@"\t•\t"])
    {

        [[textView textStorage]  addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyleForBullet range:NSMakeRange(varEndingPointOfString, strtostoreLength.length)];
    }
    else
    {


        [[textView textStorage]  addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyleNormal range:NSMakeRange(varEndingPointOfString, strtostoreLength.length)];

    }

    varEndingPointOfString = varStaringPointOfString;
    strtostoreLength =@"";
}
```

but from this the speed of typing is become very slow.

Comment: So your question changed to "How to do multiple NSParagraphStyle?" to "How optimize my code (velocity)?"? Well, shouldn't your just modify the text in range given with `shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` than doing it in all your text?

Comment: Actually i stuck in this problem and i Change the question step by step to get any idea from any one across the world. But unfortunately i didn't got any satisfactory answer. And i gave you + 1 to got your attention on this question otherwise the problem still exist and my all the question in this question areco related. But i report this to Apple with my sample code and Apple accept that this is a bug and will resolve in next build. And yes, i develope the solution of it with using the web view and html text. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setFirstHeadLineHeadIndent:firstLineIndend]; //Only the first line
[paragraphStyle setHeadIndent:headIndent]; //The rest of the lines, except the first one
[yourAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName 
                             value:paragraphStyle
                             range:paragraphRange];
```

For the bullet point, that's something different. You need to find where are the bullet point, and set another indent accordingly.

Comment: please see my question. i have problem regarding multiple paragraph. not to do task in one paragraph. I just want to set only "headIndent" for different paragraph. i am doing it by for loop and getting if the paragraph starting from bullet then headIndent is 10.0 and if not then 0.0. but from this the typing speed is getting low. so i have to look another solution. look the "Evernote" app. they do the exact same thing that i want.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Is your question about detecting new `paragraph`?

Comment: please check my "Edit after searching". hope you will get the idea from that. and one style given to any paragraph then it shouldn't come in any method to restyle again and again. that will also work for this issue.i am working on this for 1 week and didn't found any solution so asked here. and i don't know how Evernote did it. this the link of the app. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8